# Errors when running Language-Solution in MPS

Tags: dsl, mps

I'm developing an DSL with jetbrains MPS. It's not obvious to use, but I succeeded so far with the design-part.
It's possible to right-click on a solutions node and "run" it, assuming the language is executable (extends executing.util). Plus I use a seperately developed jar as a library (used by the generator).

I build a new project to test, as simple as possible, added some extra nodes and loops in the generator, the error occures and it can't be undone.

As far as I can see, there are several possible sources of errors.

- dependencies (they are tricky in MPS)
- my jar
- wrong cached files or so

Executing "run" causes the following error:

```
error: could not find or load main class MySolution.package.map_concept
```

Has some of you out there experience with this?
Tell me, if there are some extra information that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have added the jar file as a model to the language, which makes it invisible for the solution. Following the instructions at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD32/Getting+the+dependencies+right#Gettingthedependenciesright-AddingexternalJavaclassesandjarstoaprojectruntimesolutions and creating a separate library solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a problem of the generator. Have you fully rebuilt the project - right-click on the "project" node in the structure tree?
Is the root mapping template correct? If you can share your project, I can have a look.

Comment: I added you to my git-repo, hope that's okay. Rebuilding the project or making the solution causes a bunch of errors, saying that the import cannot be resolved. I red that this can be reglected.

Answer (score 0):

A small tip that could have saved me some time and might also solve this problem for someone else, even if you followed the instructions in other answers.

When prompted to add your libraries to modules after including the libraries on Java tab, dismiss the window if you already included them in the first place on the Common tab. Otherwise they are listed once despite having been added twice, leading to a compilation failure.